# PDFBox identify multiple columns

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to use PDFBox to extract text from different documents with different layouts (1, 2, or more columns) with headers and footers.
Is there a way to ensure that headers / text in multiple columns / footers are rendered correctly in order?

Comment: That depends entirely on how those PDFs are built. E.g. if the text pieces are drawn in the order you want, simply switch off the sorting property of the text stripper. Or are *beads* defined properly? Then use text stripping by beads.

Comment: I have to assume that PDFs are built as differently as possible. I currently switched off the sorting property, but for headers and footers the order can be messy. What I am currently doing is using an heuristic to understand if a line belongs to an header or footer and order it but I wanted to know if there are better strategies.

Comment: I'm afraid a really generic solution requires some AI. E.g. consider the case of newspaper pages with multi-column insets like images. Depending on the paper in question and the nature of the inset, the text in the first column above such an inset may continue with the second column above or with the first column below. Sometimes I as a human only find the correct order after trying to read it either way and determining that one way does not make sense.